# использование одной переменной в 2х компонентах vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

есть основной компонент `Surfing` в нем переменная `nolimit : false`
в этот компонент импортирую другой компонент `settings`

в computed я устанавливаю `nolimit : true`

как в компоненте `settings` мне использовать переменную `nolimit` ?

Answer (score 1):

разобрался

```
<settings :nolimit="nolimit"></settings>
```

и записал в `props`